When hovering over the menu, the menu overflows off the screen. Is there any way to fix this situation?
sub menu overfliws off the screen
It is possible to switch to a full-screen fixed menu, but I would also like to know if there are any better alternatives.I use plain PHP, not a framework.Thank you everyone for your suggestions.
